# Include AWSSDK refrence to the nant build file

Tags: amazon-web-services, build-automation, nant, nantcontrib

I'm making a build file to build a website written in C#.net using NANT, 
 but i'm Unable to include the AWSSDK assembly to the file. it give me error

`error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'S3' does not exist in the namespace 'Amazon'`

the AWSSDK is present in the c:/windows/assembly folder

and this is what i tried

`<references>
  <include name="/WINDOWS/assembly/AWSSDK.dll" />
</references>`

Note :-

`<Reference Include="AWSSDK, Version=1.3.19.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=cd2d24cd2bace800, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
          <HintPath>/WINDOWS/assembly/</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

Doesn't work i guess `Reference Include=`is not the part of the NANT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're importing the correct namespace.

`<imports>

<import namespace="Amazon.S3" />

</imports>`